# What is the correct way to phrase a statement involving the word "assign"?

Tags: language-agnostic, variable-assignment

Forgive me for such a basic question; this is (I suppose) more of an English question than a programming question; but I think as software developers we make such statements on a fairly regular basis.

If I have this code:

```
int x = 0;
```

...does the above "assign `x` to `0`", or does it "assign `0` to `x`"?

It's just been bugging me. Feel free to close if you know of a better place to be asking (though if someone provides a cogent answer before this question is closed, I will be happy).

**Edit**: The nice thing about the above code is that if I'm talking about it, I could really phrase it either way and it should be clear what I mean to any thinking human being (as `0` is not a variable). I just know I sometimes hit a mental wall when I try to explain a line like this:

```
x = y;
```

If I say "it assigns `y` to `x`", I'm saying something that (surely) means the *opposite* of what I'd be saying if I said "it assigns `x` to `y`"; yet both seem reasonable!

Oh well...

Comment: You could ask the experts over at http://english.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Not that this answers your question I imagine, but I just say "x gets 0" and leave it at that.

Comment: +1, I didn't even know that website existed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Webster.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/assign) should be pretty authoritative: For the verb "to assign", they specifically give the example "assign a value to the variable" (and, for what it's worth, that's the way I've always heard the term used). In your example, you would assign the value 0 to the variable x.

Comment: Wow, I wasn't even sure I was going to end up *accepting* an answer to this question; I can't believe they actually use that specific example. How convenient!

Answer (score 3):

In this particular case you are `assigning 0 to the variable x`.

Comment: Makes sense to me. Problem is, so does the opposite answer!

Answer (score 2):

It's "assign 0 to x", or "set x to 0".